# how to add multiple instances of jquery colour picker with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, colors, picker

I'm using eyecon colorpicker.js to edit colours on front end of a website. This script works perfectly as is but am struggling to make multiple instances of it so I can change multiple elements also need a way to reset the colors back to default value.

What's the best way to achieve this?

```
<label>Body</label>
<div id="colorSelector">
 <div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
            var col = '000000';

            function updateCookieInfo(c){

                $("#colorSelector div").css("background-color", "#" + c);
                $("body").css("background-color", "#" + c);
            }

            if(typeof $.cookie('color') != 'undefined'){
                col = $.cookie('color');
                updateCookieInfo(col);
            }

            $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
                color: col,
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                    $.cookie('color', col, { expires: 7 });
                    updateCookieInfo(col);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    col = hex;
                    $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                    $("#colorSelector div").css("background-color", "#" + c);
                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some hours trying to solve that problem as well and at the end I gave up and decided to use [jscolor](http://jscolor.com)

It's not as fancy as the one of eyecon but it worked fine for me - I needed 15 different color picker on one page - and at least there is a documentation with few samples on the website.

So I know that it does not really answer your question but it should handle the problem you're trying to solve.